# Want to filter and map an array with an id

Tags: reactjs, filter, split, array.prototype.map

I'm in little bit confusion in my code. I have an array,

```
let arr = [{id:"225",name:"jin"},
           {id:"226, 228",name:"villy"},
           {id:"225",name:"lil"},
           {id:"202,236,289",name:"kill"}]
```

I stored an ID in a variable called `testid`. I want to filter my array `"arr"` which holds the `"testid"`. My `testid`, for example, is 228. So I want this object from the array with the `{id:"226, 228", name: "Villy"}`. Could you please assist me in resolving this problem? I use map and filter out everything, but there is some confusion.

This is the code that I tried, every time sae result is coming as result for different testid

```
{this.state.testid && arr && arr.filter((dd) =>(dd.id.split(", ").map((d) => d === this.state.testid)))
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried to implement, so we can try to help you find your mistake?

Comment: @TheTisiboth {this.state.testid && arr && arr.filter((dd) =>(dd.id.split(", ").map((d) => d === this.state.testid)))

Comment: what is working/not working? Please update your post with those information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a single object, you can use `find`.

You can create a function that takes the array and the test id, and returns the found object:

```js
const findTestId = (arr, testId) => {
    return arr.find((i) => i.id.includes(String(testId)))
}
```

To get an array with the found objects, you can do the same with `filter`:

```js
const filterTestId = (arr, testId) => {
    return arr.filter((i) => i.id.includes(String(testId)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First we can find the index of array then you can reach your data with it

```
 arr[arr.findIndex(item => item.id === tested)]
```